# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "duro" y "arduo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Estoy interesado en las diferencias de uso en estos adjetivos. Leyendo el diccionario, solamente veo que "arduo" es más formal. ¿Aparte de eso hay algunas otras diferencias?

Answer (score 2):

«Arduo» significa «muy difícil»; solamente se intercambia con «duro» bajo ese significado.

«Duro», por otra parte, podría significar *violento, cruel* o *insensible*, que no recaen en la definición de «muy difícil».

Comment: Añado: la otra acepción en DRAE es "Dicho de un terreno: Áspero y fragoso." Se extrapola a lo demás, es decir, que "arduo" implica cierto sufrimiento o padecimiento; así que puede ser más que duro, pero sólo con el significado de díficil, como tú dices.